# Admin User Login Using 2 Tables PhP

Tags: php, mysql

The situation is, I need to create a login with user level without using drop-down or radios button plus it has two tables one for the use and for the admin. i already tried creating it in various ways but it still doesn't go to the user page

Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('configure.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
$date = date("y/m/d h:i:a");
$usern = $_POST['username'];
$passw = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['admin'] = '';
$_SESSION['user'] = '';

$sql = " SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$usern' AND password = '$passw'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['username'] = $usern && $row['password'] = $passw){
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $usern;
            header("location: ../login_admin.php?log=".$_SESSION['admin']);
         }
    }
}else{
    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usern' AND password = '$passw'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    if($result1->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             if($row['username'] = $usern && $row['password'] = $passw){
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $usern;
                    header("location: ../main.php?log=".$_SESSION['user']);
             }else{
                    header("location:  SpaceAdv/index.php");
             }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

P.S. the configure.php is the connection to the database and the localhost aswell thank you

Comment: `if($row['username'] == $usern && $row['password'] == $passw)` you also don't need this if since you already check using the SQL query, and it is `==`, not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code fix with your architecture**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('configure.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
$date = date("y/m/d h:i:a");
$usern = $_POST['username'];
$passw = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['admin'] = '';
$_SESSION['user'] = '';

$sql = " SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$usern' AND password = '$passw'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
    //Current user is in Admin table, hence he/she is an admin
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $usern;
    header("location: ../login_admin.php?log=".$_SESSION['admin']);
    exit(0);
} elseif ($result->num_rows > 1) {
      //there should not be more than one rows with same credentials. Two rows with same (username, password), Make username primary key.
      throw new Exception("Multiple entry with same username and password in admin table");
} else {
    //Given credentials are not in admin table, check user table.
    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usern' AND password = '$passw'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $usern;
        header("location: ../main.php?log=".$_SESSION['user']);
    } elseif ($result->num_rows > 1) {
        throw new Exception("Multiple entry with same username and password in user table");
    }
    else {
        //Nither in User nor in admin table
        header("location:  SpaceAdv/index.php");
    }


}

?>
```

## Recommended approach

Please read few articles on role based access control. Below is a great article about how to implement the same.

https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

This is not working properly. I have tried many time. When I try to access from two table to make one login with limited access to pages through session. My login page vanished. Why this is Happened before this page was working accurately. ACCORDING TO ANSWER NO ONE.I have already posted my problem on STACKOVERFLOW "make one login from two different tables and access pages to users and admin". Please! overview this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add another field in your database and name it as (`TYPE, VARCHAR(50)`) that will store as an ADMIN or USER during registration, in that way you can already determine if the person who will log-in in your app if he/she is a user or an admin.

Comment: Well unfortunately our TA wanted it as Two Table Login it is a project in college but good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
function logIn()
{
    if ($this->logDetails($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password')) == 1) 
    {

        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`username`='".$_POST['username']."' OR `email`='".$_POST['username']."') ")->row_array();
        $user_type = $this->db->get_where('user_type', array('id'=>$result['user_type']))->row_array();

        if ($user_type['id']=='1')//admin login 
        {
            $controller = $user_type['controller'];
            $userdata = array('map_user' => $result['username'], 'mapCtrl' => $controller, 'aId' => $result['id'], 'uId' => $result['id'], 'aEmail' => $result['email'], 'type' => $result['user_type']);
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            redirect($controller);
        }
        if ($user_type['id']=='2')//User login
        {
            $controller = $user_type['controller'];
            $userdata = array('map_user' => $result['username'], 'mapCtrl' => $controller, 'aId' => $result['id'], 'uId' => $result['id'], 'aEmail' => $result['email'], 'type' => $result['user_type']);
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            redirect($controller);
        }
        $this->index();
    }else{
        $this->index('Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}
function logDetails($username,$password)
{
    return $this->db->query("Select * from users where (username='".$username."' OR email='".$username."') and password='".md5($password)."'")->num_rows();
}
```

This is controlling the login

class Admin extends CI_Controller 
{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin');//sql querys to store data
    if(!$this->session->userdata('aId') && $this->router->class != 'Login')
    {
        redirect('Login/index');
    }else if($this->session->userdata('aId') && $this->router->class=='Login' && $this->router->method!='shutdown')
    {
        redirect('admin/index');
    }
}
```

}
class User extends CI_Controller 
{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user');//sql querys to store data
    if(!$this->session->userdata('aId') && $this->router->class != 'Login')
    {
        redirect('Login/index');
    }else if($this->session->userdata('aId') && $this->router->class =='Login' && $this->router->method!='shutdown')
    {

        redirect('user/index');
    }
}
```

}
class Login_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
    if(!$this->session->userdata('map_user') && $this->router->class != 'Login')
    {
        redirect('Login/index');
    }else if($this->session->userdata('map_user') && $this->router->class=='Login' && $this->router->method!='shutdown')
    {
        redirect($this->session->userdata('mapCtrl'));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still not familiar with this kind of PHP